# Склонение по падежам математических величин

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно произнести?
Можно ли общепринятые в математике переменные величины "икс" и "игрек" произносить, изменяя эти слова по падежам: например "к иксу", "от игрека" и т. д.?

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно. Названия букв всегда склоняются, если только к тому есть возможность. Ср. ера, ятем и т. п.
Только учтите, что в математическом жаргоне обычно иксА, иксУ и т. д. А обычной речи нормативно Икса, Иксу и т. д.